# Saving data frames to values in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of titles that I would like to iterate over and create/save data frames to. I have tried the using the `paste()` function (as seen below) but that does not work for me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
samples <- list("A","B","C")

for (i in samples){ 
    paste(i,sumT,sep="_") <- data.frame(col1=NA,col1=NA)
    }
```

My desired output is  three empty data frames named: `A_sumT`, `B_sumT` and `C_sumT`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer with `purrr`.

```
samples <- list("A", "B", "C")

samples %>% 
     purrr::map(~ data.frame()) %>% 
     purrr::set_names(~ paste(samples, "sumT", sep="_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a list of dataframes and avoid many separate objects flooding global environment as this example can extend to hundreds and not just three. Plus with this approach, you will maintain **one** container capable of running bulk operations across all dataframes.

By using `sapply` below on a character vector, you create a named list:

```
samples <- c("A","B","C")   # OR unlist(list("A","B","C"))

df_list <- sapply(samples, function(x) data.frame(col1=NA,col2=NA), simplify=FALSE)

# RUN ANY DATAFRAME OPERATION
head(df_list$A)
tail(df_list$B)
summary(df_list$C)

# BULK OPERATIONS
stacked_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
stacked_df <- do.call(cbind, df_list)
merged_df <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="col1"), df_list)
```

Or if you need to rename list

```
# RENAME LIST
df_list <- setNames(df_list, paste0(samples, "_sumT"))

# RUN ANY DATAFRAME OPERATION
head(df_list$A_sumT)
tail(df_list$B_sumT)
summary(df_list$C_sumT)
```

Comment: That will be very useful, thank you for the feedback! I will try to apply that and let you know how it goes.